# Python: Saving result from loop to a variable

Tags: python, xml, loops

I am storing specific information from an XML file to a variable.
The XML file contains a lot of information, but I am just looking for something called nAtt.

I am reading the XML file into a data frame:

```
df = pd.read_xml(folder_path2 + filename6)
```

nAtt contains either 0, 1, 2 or 3 and it looks like nAtt=" 0"

So, I say

```
nAtt = df["nAtt"].dropna().to_numpy()
```

to save the value from the XML file to a variable called nAtt in my code.

Now, I am trying to loop over nAtt to check if it is either 0, 1, 2 or 3 and depending on the result I want to set another variable called nAtt_change to a specfic value:

```
for 0 in nAtt:
nAtt_change = 0
for 1 in nAtt:
nAtt_change = -6
for 2 in nAtt:
nAtt_change = -10
for 3 in nAtt:
nAtt_change = -20
```

However, I get this error message:

for 0 in nAtt:
^
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal

Can anyone tell me what I need to change to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: The code sample you provided for your "for" loops is not valid Python.

Comment: You seem to confuse numpy arrays with python lists. Numpy has many vectorized methods to check its elements without looping.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear but I suppose you want to do something like this:

```
nAtt_change = np.zeros(shape = len(nAtt))

for i in range(len(nAtt)):
   if nAtt[i] == 0:
      nAtt_change[i] = yourSpecificValue
   ...
```

Change `yourSPecificValue` to the value you want and add other if statements for the rest of the `nAtt` values.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want, but I receive a Traceback error regarding: nAtt = df25["nAtt"].dropna().to_numpy()       Might this be related to the fact that nAtt in the xml says nAtt=" 0" instead of nAtt="0"   ?

Comment: Yes, that seems like a potential source of the error. Use `.strip()` method to get rid of any leading spaces

Comment: Thanks. It is solved now with removing the spaces in the XML!